# Statement label in ENDDO not matching DO label

Tags: loops, fortran

I wrote a program to check if a number is prime or not.

Here is the code:

```
program prime
integer n,i
print *, 'enter a number'
read *,n
do 10,i=2,n-1
    if(mod(n,i).eq.0.0) then
        print*, 'it is not prime'
        read*
        stop
    end if
continue
if(n.eq.i)print *, 'it is prime'
read *
stop
end do
end program
```

However, there was a problem. I got an error:

```
Error: Statement label in ENDDO doesn't match DO label
```

The error in itself was understandable, the end do was not connected with the do loop. However, I cannot connect it as the program will not let me do so. Why is this?

Comment: Please share the error :)

Comment: @Roboroads
\Error: Statement label in ENDDO  doesn't match DO label|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: You probably don't want to do `.eq.0.0`. Equality comparison with a float is a bad idea. In this case you can just do equality comparison with an integer, `.eq.0` or even` == 0`.

Comment: Also, your `n.eq.i` is using `i` outside of the loop in which it is defined.

Comment: @veryreverie, `n.eq.i` outside the loop would appear to be correct given the logic (with code correction to ensure it is outside the loop): if `i` has value `n` it has that value because the DO construct completed all of its iterations without a premature `stop`.

Comment: I am getting a load of good advice here. Thanks. Let me try to implement it.

Comment: I am going to be honest, I find fortran rather confusing with respect to c or c++ despite it being supposedly more basic than those ones.

Comment: @Jon There are definitely some gotchas in Fortran caused by some historical baggage, but you are really inviting the problems by using some old style things. Use `==` instead of `.eq.`, Use consistent indentation inside the do loop. Do not try to use any labels. Basically, I suggest to avoid any old learning resources, there is enough of the modern ones. Learn modern Fortran first, then learn the old features.

Comment: @francescalus True, but I think it just ends up being a confusing way of writing `if (.true.)`, as if the `stop` is called the `if` line is never reached? Also, I feel like using loop variables outside of loops is bad practice, even if Fortran allows it.

Comment: @VladimirF Sadly, the compiler I am using does not let me do '=='.

Comment: @Jon It MUST let you do it. This is standard Fortran 90. And your coe has also other Fortran 90+ features. What compiler do you even use?

Comment: @VladimirF GNU Fortran compiler.

Comment: @Jon If you mean gfortran and not g77, then there is no problem with `==` in gfortran.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, gfortran. Ok, I will look to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the statement

```
do 10,i=2,n-1
```

you are introducing a *labelled DO construct*.  A labelled DO construct needs an appropriate termination statement, with matching label.  In current Fortran, a matching labelled DO construct is terminated with

```
10 end do
```

or

```
10 continue
```

Labelled DO constructs are obsolescent in current Fortran, so the entire DO construct of the question can instead be written as

```
do i=2,n-1
   ...
end do
```

---

In the question, there is horribly confusing indentation.  The `continue` statement is perhaps intended as the termination of the loop, but it isn't because it isn't labelled `10`. `continue` is just a normal, do nothing, statement which has significance as a loop termination only through its label. Instead, the compiler sees the loop terminated by the `end do`, regardless of indentation, and then complains because it's missing the appropriate label.

The logic of the loop agrees with the indentation: the `continue` statement should be the end of the loop. There are three options

1. add a label `10` to the statement
2. change the `continue` to `10 end do`
3. remove the `10` from the DO statement and change `continue` to `end do`

For each option, also delete the second `end do`.

Finally, with

```
if(n.eq.i) ...
```

coming after the loop, that condition is redundant: `i` will always have value `n` if it's reached.

Comment: I have removed the '10' in the do loop and it has fixed half the issue.

Comment: What is the unfixed half?

Comment: the bit where it says 'it is prime'.

Comment: You will also need to move the `end do` to where the `continue` is originally. The "it is prime" must be outside the loop. If it's inside the loop, you know `i` will never have value `n`, because the loop goes up only to `n-1`.

Comment: it is does not print that statement. So, I am guessing is it something to do with that continue part?

Comment: This has resolved the issue. I did not realise that the continue just ended the loop. I need to really read this loop properly because I clearly misapplied it.  Either way, Thanks so much!

Comment: The `continue` _didn't_ end the loop.  It would have if it had been `10 continue` (which probably was the intention), but in that case the `end do` is wrong, because it's not closing any other loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239891/discussion-between-jon-and-francescalus).

Answer (score -1):

```
program prime
integer n,i    
print*, 'enter a number'
read*,n
do i=2,n-1
    if (mod(n,i)==0.0) then
        print*, 'it is not prime'
        read*
        stop
    end if
end do
if (n==i) then
    print*, 'it is prime'
    read*
endif
end program prime
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, just a code snippet isn't sufficient here. What are the intentions, why was the original of OP not correct etc...

Comment: @albert it was because of the continue

Comment: Well the answer-er should mention these things in the answer as otherwise no-one knows what his intentions are / were.

Comment: @albert, check out francescalus's answer.

Comment: I know that answer, this is about this answer! there is no reference to to the answer from francescaus or better said no reference or explanation at all.

Comment: @albert Ah, I get what you are saying. My apologies for the misunderstanding. Maybe, the person assumed we can read between the lines.

Comment: @albert You are right, I should probably elaborate more. But there were plenty of comments and also the accepted answer was plenty informative. Since there was an answer already picked I just wanted to provide a clear code snippet because the previous answer was a bit "too informative"

Comment: @Monochromatic  You should state that reason in your answer and maybe specify what you changed / intentions were. People not always check all answers / comments and at that moment it is hard to see what the code snippet solves.